# exec and only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: exec, php

I'm using the [PHP export script from 1 and 1](http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/mysql/13.html):

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db123456789';
$mysqlUserName ='dbo123456789';
$mysqlPassword ='myPassword';
$mysqlHostName ='db1234.perfora.net';
$mysqlExportPath ='chooseFilenameForBackup.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}
?>
```

If I'm executing it I get `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in` and it points to this line

```
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
```

How should I adapt the script?

Comment: http://php.net/exec <- please re-read how to use that function. -- http://php.net/language.references.pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define `$output` before calling `exec`:

```
$output = array();
exec($command, $output, $worked);
```

The error occurs because PHP does not like being passed values created on the spot as a reference (even though in this case it would be perfectly obvious to a more advanced compiler how this should not be an issue).

Comment: And the reason is, that `$output=array()` is an **expression** that resolves to the value of `$output` after assigning it to `array()`. That's some bad code from 1and1, assigning array() does not even make sense.

Comment: @fab: Actually it does not resolve to the value of `$output` (otherwise it could reference that and everything would be fine), it resolves to `array()` and that's the problem. Try some chain assignments with dynamic properties using `__get()` on an object to see the difference. Assignment in PHP does not work like it does in e.g. C++.

Comment: Both is correct. The **value** of $output **is** `array()` *after* assigning it. And no, PHP could not reference it because it is no ZVal container, just a plain value.

Comment: @fab: [This](http://ideone.com/UCvBHc) is what I 'm referring to. I believe the behavior of the assignment operator is to blame, and I find it hard to accept that PHP *could* not reference it. I can accept that it *does* not do so.

Comment: Agreed. A typical case of "well, because PHP"

Comment: `You need to define $output before calling exec` => incorrect. Not necessary.

Comment: @mark: Changed "need" to "should", because you are technically correct. But I consider it bad form to not explicitly initialize variables to make it obvious what's going on there, and I would never endorse it. Otherwise the reader has to *know* how `exec` works, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do not assign inside the function call, just call it like:

```
exec($command, $output, $worked);
```

The $output var does not have to be initialized first, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in my comment above, this is just a little mistake you made, which is very easy to correct.

In general you can only pass variables by reference, but you passed an expression for such a [*pass-by-reference* function parameter](http://php.net/language.references.pass).

Passing a variable instead of giving an expression will fix your issue and the warning will go away.

For example use

```
$output             # variable
```

instead of

```
 $output = array()  # expression
```

for the second parameter.

---

***Fun Fact:*** The variable types for such return by reference parameters are return - not input - types. That means, you don't need to make `$output`  be an array before passing the variable. You only need to pass the variable and you wil get back an array.